# How can I creat this workspace in UV editor?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I would like to create a similar workflow. I've downloaded a file from a popular free 3d Model website, so I noticed that I like the workflow, in the file, many objects, not matter the shaper they are, you can match the geometry in the UV place, notice that there are just rectangle with texture on it. I used to use texture paint and many tools in UV, even texture atlasing, but I would like to make this 4 funny stuff.

[image]

Comment: Why not paste your images directly here? Site like the one used just load as blanks my side of the globe...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could recommend you try watch [Game Asset Creation](https://cloud.blender.org/p/game-asset-creation/) available on Blender Cloud. It covers a number of approaches from adjusting existing textures to drawing directly on meshes. The combination of multiple bakes, and organizing UV's I found particularly helpful. There are some free video. From the preview images you can also get an idea what is covered in the other chapters. Certainly more information than could fit in a reply here...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not totally sure what you are asking, but, my best guess is that your the image shown is just one texture and the UV maps are just moved to cover one section of the texture. You can grab, resize, etc. within UV edit mode by just grabbing the points.

Comment: yes I noticed that if I grab or edit the geometry in the uv editor I can create every objects and match the uvs coordinate with the texture, But I want to create the texture , I do not know how to put these textures on the canvas. Perphaps photoshop create the texture and then load it ?

Comment: Yeah, I use old Photoshop 10 then move it to blender to open the actual window and get a texture to it there are many videos that I've watched, but I'll try to explain If you are you using blender render then you have to click the mesh, make it a shadeless in the materials tab, then in the texture tab beside it hit new, open(open your texture), unwrap your mesh (If you don't know how then watch a video) and then either use the top left of the blender screen where it says file, help and such, just to the right it says default change it too UV editing and then open you texture in that window.

Comment: ok , yes I know the process of unwrapping and some tooles, but I ve never consider photoshop, I mean, I use photoshop for painting or make some texture, seamless, clone or even paint the UV layout, but ok I am going to do the texture in photoshop and then, export that image in my Uv layout and finally move, grab and place the UV coordinates in the uv editor.